# Post values using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, development-environment

I am currently new to android . I am using this site for practice: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/, I am trying to use the post request 
here is the code I am using, I have used `jsonschema2pojo` and I created two classes so that has confused me, why do we need two classes? and how to use them? The code is not crashing. But , I get null when I display the values in a toast.

JsonPlaceholer.java

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("create")
Call<Post> createPost(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textViewResult;

private JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           // .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .baseUrl("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

    createPost();
  }

private void createPost() {

    //Post post = new Post(23, "New Title", "New Text");

    Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
    fields.put("name", "NewName");
    fields.put("salary", "123");
    fields.put("age","12");

    Call<Post> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createPost(fields);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

            Post postResponse = response.body();

            String content = "";
            content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
            content += "ID: " + postResponse.getId() + "\n";

            content += "Name : " + postResponse.getName() + "\n";
            content += "Salary : " + postResponse.getSalary() + "\n";
            content += "Age :" + postResponse.getAge() + "\n\n";

           // textViewResult2.setText(content);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ans::"+content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {

            //textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
 }
```

Post.java

```
public class Post {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("salary")
@Expose
private String salary;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


}
```

PostR.java

```
public class PostR {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Post data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Post getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Post data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

Comment: check with log first , data is blank or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 classes are for the DTO (data transfer object), **mapping the response from the API eith Java objects** and **mapping the response data with Java objects**.

> Replace your code with below code, it should work:

```
Call<PostR> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createPost(fields);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PostR>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostR> call, Response<PostR> response) {    
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }    
            PostR postRResponse = response.body();
            Post postResponse = postRResponse.getData();
            if(postResponse!=null) {
                String content = "";
                content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
                content += "ID: " + postResponse.getId() + "\n";    
                content += "Name : " + postResponse.getName() + "\n";
                content += "Salary : " + postResponse.getSalary() + "\n";
                content += "Age :" + postResponse.getAge() + "\n\n";
            }
           // textViewResult2.setText(content);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ans::"+content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostR> call, Throwable t) {    
            //textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

> **P.S** - General Process you can follow to test API:

1. Check if the Backend (API) is working or not using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
2. Print response.code() and response.body() in Log.
3. Check if the structure (keys/params) of response is same as PostR.java
4. Check if the structure (keys/params) of response.body() is same as Post.java class.
5. If all the above works as expected, your Toast should print correct values.

Comment: Even after the edits your code still contains serious errors, have fixed them for you please check. You should have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Ok on having a quick look, your PostR.java is the POJO class for the response you receive from callback and Post.java is the POJO class for what is returned in `data` So in your `MainActivity.java` you need to replace all `Call<Post>` with `Call<PostR>` as PostR.java is the response you get with Post object in it.

Try and see if this helps.

**EDIT:** don't forget to replace `Callback<Post>` and  `Response<Post>` with `Callback<PostR>` and `Response<PostR>` too

Comment: Ok the nested jsons are really troublesome for me i have managed to post the data but i am also trying to retrieve the complete data so do i have to follow similar steps for retrieving also?

Comment: @sagar The answer you marked accepted even though edited still has errors in its code. I'll put up an edit request to fix it. You  can't map response.body() to your Post class object directly as the retreived data maps to an object of PostR.java. So you have to map an object for PostR instead like ```PostR postRResponse = response.body();``` then create the object for Post like so ```Post post = postRResponse.getData();```
.This might be the reason why you still weren't getting the data.